# jQuery display dynamic div by choosing different checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display contact information by choosing different `checkbox`, like this picture:

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    $(this).closest('div').css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

```css
.receipt_info{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="receipt[]"/>
      </td>
      <td>Option1
        <div class="receipt_info">
          <div>
            <label>name1</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>phone1</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>address1</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="receipt[]"/>
      </td>
      <td>Option2
        <div class="receipt_info">
          <div>
            <label>name2</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>phone2</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>address2</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I think I'm selecting wrong `div`, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Please try answer I provided below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`$(this).closest('tr').find('div.receipt_info')`** selector!

- `this` refers to element on which `event` is invoked.
- `jQuery.closest` will traverse up in `DOMTree` and returned matched element.
- `jQuery.find` will find all the child of he current element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    $('.receipt_info').hide();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('div.receipt_info').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.receipt_info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="receipt[]" />
      </td>
      <td>Option1
        <div class="receipt_info">
          <div>
            <label>name1</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>phone1</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>address1</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="receipt[]" />
      </td>
      <td>Option2
        <div class="receipt_info">
          <div>
            <label>name2</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>phone2</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>address2</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Through your `div` and the checkbox are seperated by `td` you should use jQuerys [`parents`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) to get the parent `tr` and from there start searching for the corresponding `receipt_info`.

Like so:

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('.receipt_info').show();
```

I edited your jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xee3s501/4/).

Comment: Thank, it's a quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

You need to first find the parent tr in which the required div is,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('tr').find('div.receipt_info').css("display", "block");
    }
    else
    {
     $(this).closest('tr').find('div.receipt_info').css("display", "none");
    }
  });
});
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9n9pfhe5/1/

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to say that the contact info should hide, too.